# Change Enable Partial Rendering value of script manager during runtime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I need to change Enable Partial Rendering value which is declared inside a script manager during runtime. In my website script manager is declared in master page.

Sample code is given below

```
((System.Web.UI.ScriptManager)this.Master.FindControl("scriptmgr")).EnablePartialRendering = true;
```

While executing the above line i am getting an error

> "The EnablePartialRendering property cannot be changed after the Init
>   event."

How to solve the error and i need enable partial rendering value dynamically for a particular page.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Move that code to the page init or page preinit event, according to the error.